# barman installation without root priviledges - where to put barman.conf?

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman

I am trying to figure out a **Barman-2.13 installation** via Ansible from the [source code from github](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/barman/releases/download/) as barman user inside `/opt/barman` (which also is the `home` of the barman user).
I use the [barman manual](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.13/#installation-from-sources) as a guideline.

The challenge I am facing is that I do not have root priviledges on the target (a rhel8 VM) and likewise can not use `/etc/barman` which is the default location for the `barman.conf` file.

How would you go about this? Or, in other words, where to put the barman.conf and have barman know about it? I wonder whether I have to adjust the setup.py for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I found the answer [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgbarman/tickets/94/)

in short ... a `$HOME/.barman.conf` (home dir of the `barman` user) overrides the default systemwide `/etc/barman/barman.conf`.

If things are set up this way you would not need `sudo` any longer. Neiterh for installing, nor operating barman I think.

If this is not accurate I am happy to hear arguments on why not.

Comment: Yes, I confirm that's the right approach (having designed that interface). I provided the explanation here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgbarman/tickets/94/#b748/9e65

The idea of the /etc file is to be managed via configuration managers and as such we recommend that permissions stay as 'root'. Nothing/nobody prevents you from having one instance of Barman per system user, each with their own configuration files in the home directory and individual cron entries. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [barman manual](https://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.13/index.html#system-requirements) clearly states in several places that some commands **must** be run as the **root** user, for example:

> Installing Barman is as easy. **As root user** simply type:
> . . .
> Then, **as root** simply type:

Simply put, if you do not already *have* this access to your VM, then you need to *get* it.
You *might* be able to get a "single-user" installation up and running without root/sudo access to the VM, but I *seriously* recommend you get yourself the Right Tools for the the Right Job.

Comment: you mean barman operation requires sudo, right? I have not gotten that far I have to admit.

Comment: Correct.  At the very least, you ought to have it for installation and upgrades.  I don't know if you need it for "day-to-day" operations.

Comment: well if you don't need it for day to day operations, then you don't need it. You just have to answer the question at hand here: "where to put the barman.conf & conf.d/* files else than /etc/barman?" The Installation runs through without sudo as barman user (i.e). Or am I misunderstanding something fundamentally?

Comment: @vrms: So how do you intend to /install/ the software?  
Package Managers are usually restricted for use by the root user only.

Comment: 1.) download and unpack the archive as the barman user, 2.) run `./setup.py` with the `--user` flag ... should install barman in the `home` of the user running the script. As it is described in the `installation from sources` section of the [manual](https://deac-riga.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pgbarman/2.12/manual.pdf)